# Uniform Initialization and default constructor arguments in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, uniform-initialization

I am learning about new C++11 feature - uniform initialization. Wrote small program:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

class C {
public:
    C(int a = 1, int b = 2) : a_{a}, b_{b}, n{0,1,2,3,4} {};
    int n[5];
    int a_,b_;

};

int main()
{
    C c = C{}; // should call C(int a = 1, int b = 2) with default arg.
    cout << c.a_ << "  " << c.b_ << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting unexpected result `0  0`. In other words, everything is initialized to zero. The only way this could have happened: 1. Implicit default constructor was called, or 2. Initialization was not done correctly. (3. Compiler ???)

Why am I getting unexpected results ? Were there any changes to Constructor syntax that uses Uniform initialization in C++11 ?

EDIT: Using latest Intel Compiler:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Unif_Init (Intel C++ 13.0), Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>  xilink: executing 'link'
1>  xilink: executing 'link'
1>  Unif_Init.vcxproj -> C:\Users\alex\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Unif_Init\Debug\Unif_Init.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: What compiler? I cannot reproduce with gcc.

Comment: @JesseGood Intel C++ Compiler 13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bug in the compiler. `C{}` calls the default constructor to create a temporary which is used to copy-initialize the object `c`. `C(int a = 1, int b = 2)` is obviously a default one so it should use that. Does switching the initialization order to the order declared in the class help (probably not, but just a guess)? It seems the intel compiler isn't considering your ctor with default arguments as the default one.

```
C(int a = 1, int b = 2) : n{0,1,2,3,4}, a_{a}, b_{b} {};
```

Comment: Tried your version, same thing.
On top of that, I just tried `int* pi = new int[4] {1,2,3,4};` and got error `1>Source.cpp(18): error : expected a ";"
1>     int* pi = new int[4] {1,2,3,4};//C++09` So, looks like Intel Compiler is not fully C++11 compliment and has some bugs. Otherwise, it is best compiler out-there.

Comment: @JesseGood: "copy-initializes the object" It does not copy-initialize the object.

Comment: @NicolBolas: AFAIK, the code would call the default constructor to create a temporary and then call the move ctor to move the temporary to `c`. I thought this was called `copy-initialization`, what am I missing?

Comment: @JesseGood: What you describe is copy initialization, but that's not what it does. It does direct-list-initialization. There's no copying involved.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I think that this might have been due to my poor wording. Yes, `C{}` is direct-list-initialization, but I was talking about the line `C c = C{};`, where `C{}` initializes a temporary which is then used to copy-initialize `c` (I've updated the wording).